# Compare the position of two elements in the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two elements i.e. a canvas and a div as given below. I would like to know how I can find out if the div contains the canvas element (not in terms of DOM placement but in terms of position).

```
<canvas id="smallBall" style="position: relative; top: 52px; left: -89.0781px;"></canvas>
...
<div class="container">
<div id="hereIGo">The small ball is supposed to be contained in this DIV</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: You can retrieve the `offset().top`, `offset().left` of both elements along with their `width()` and `height()` and compare them.

Comment: That's correct. Could you post it as an answer please?

Comment: You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is using `getBoundingClientRect()`, which will retrieve the exact position of an element on the page, independent of any position relatives or absolutes. Then the comparison could be:

```
// Both of these are the results of calling getBoundingClientRect() on their respective elements.
var canvas;
var div;

if (div.top >= canvas.top &&
    div.left >= canvas.top &&
    div.right <= canvas.right &&
    div.bottom <= canvas.bottom) {
       //the div is inside the canvas.
    }
```

You also have a jQuery option, which consists of calling `$(selector).offset()`. This returns an object, with a similar interface to the one described above. This solution is as you can image more supported.